# Netgear r6700ax - guest network can access my ISP router and other computers. Chrome cast not working

Tags: router, netgear-router

https://i.stack.imgur.com/21ryW.png

I have my ISP router 192.168.50.1 which provides internet.

My TV (192.168.50.20)
PC1 (192.168.50.10)
are connected to it.

I bought a Netgear r6700ax; I connected the wan port to the ISP router.

It seems to create its own subnet 10.0.0.1.

I have enabled wifi and guest wifi (with not allowing access to other devices on the network) on this router.

Phone1 is connected to wifi of the netgear (10.0.0.2)
Phone2 is connected to the guest wifi of the netgear (10.0.0.3)

Phone1 (main wifi of netgear) can see and communicate all other devices:

- ISP router (192.168.50.1)
- TV1 (192.168.50.20)
- Phone2 (10.0.0.3)
- PC1(192.168.50.10)

=> so all ok

I have two major issues:

1. Phone2 (guest wifi of netgear) can see and communicate:

- ISP router (192.168.50.1)
- PC1 (192.168.50.10)

=> which is not normal as guest wifi devices should NOT see any of my network especially my ISP router.

2. Phone1 (main wifi of netgear) doesn't detect chromecast (of my TV 192.168.50.20) on youtube app or any other apps.

I am not sure how to solve these issues.

Comment: Go into you Wireless Settings (Router) and Enable wireless isolation.

Comment: I haven't seen anything called wireless isolation in my router settings

Comment: See if this general Netgear article helps you   https://kb.netgear.com/000062531/How-do-I-set-up-client-isolation-on-my-NETGEAR-wireless-access-point-using-Insight-Cloud-Portal    .... If your router does not provide wireless isolation then you cannot prevent devices from seeing each other.

Comment: no there's no such setting... went on every page in the router admin; it seems pretty limited that thing...it's a shame and guest wifi is pretty misleading... they can access pretty much everything on my network except netgear router page.

Comment: Disabling DHCP on the modem and the connecting everything to your router is one solution or reverse that process and modify the router configuration so DHCP is disabled on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Phone2 (guest wifi of netgear) can see and communicate ....  which is
> not normal as guest wifi devices should NOT see any of my network
> especially my ISP router.

Wireless Isolation is not completely common on consumer routers, so your router (based on your research from the article I posted) does not have this feature and you cannot isolate your guest devices this way.

Also the router you have does not appear to offer VLAN capability (also not common in consumer routers). So with the router you have, you cannot isolate using VLANs.

> Phone1 (main wifi of netgear) doesn't detect chromecast (of my TV
> 192.168.50.20) on youtube app or any other apps.

Make sure your routers (yours, ISP) are on the same subnet. The general way is to connect LAN port to LAN port and have just ONE DHCP server.  The ISP may expect you to use a specific LAN port so you do need to ask them about this.

If you need wireless guest isolation then you need a better router.  IMHO, in a home (residence) network, wireless guest isolation is a bit overblown. You may not really need it.

Comment: well that sucks. I thought the Netgear r6700ax was more advanced consumer router. It is a shame I can't flash openwrt or tomato router on it... my 5 times cheaper asus router with tomato is much more capable than the Netgear r6700a; it's just the wifi is not good enough

Comment: It is probably a decent router, but as I noted, many consumer routers do not sport wireless isolation and most do not have VLANs  - these are more advanced concepts.  You can likely survive happily without these concepts.

Comment: honestly I don't like the idea of visitors at my home connecting to my guest wifi but still have access to stuff on my network when they are not supposed to.

Comment: You can secure your existing wireless router and secure the password. Then add a second wireless router just for guests.  Put it on a different subnet. Or, you can upgrade your Netgear to a router that has wireless isolation built it.

Comment: thx for the suggestion. I just bought the netgear. I will probably buy another AP and connect it to my tomato router and separate it in a vlan for guests.